# Is it possible to go from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3 at Abu Dhabi (AUH) airside (without leaving security)?

Tags: airport-terminals, auh

I have a flight departing out of Terminal 3, but I'd like to use the lounges available in Terminal 1 (e.g. for Priority Pass, for which there are no lounges available in Terminal 3).

After clearing Immigration and Security at Terminal 3, can I get to Terminal 1 staying airside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Terminal 1 and Terminal 3 are adjacent to each other. The odd terminal is Terminal 2, which is a few kilometers away.

Comment: Thanks! I found that it was about a 15 minute airside walk from Terminal 1 - Terminal 3.